# char and byte with final access modifier - java

Tags: java, char, byte, primitive, scjp

Please take a look at below example i cant understand the relation between char and byte

```
byte b = 1;
char c = 2;

c = b; // line 1
```

Give me compilation Error because c is type of `char` and b is type of `byte` so casting is must in such condition

but now the tweest here is when i run below code

```
final byte b = 1;
char c = 2;

c = b; // line 2
```

line 2 compile successfully it doesn't need any casting at all
so my question is why `char` c behave different when i use final access modifier with `byte`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because qualifying it with `final` makes the variable a constant variable, which is a [constant expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28). So

```
final byte b = 1;
char c = 2;

c = b; // line 2
```

actually becomes

```
final byte b = 1;
char c = 2;

c = 1;
```

And the compiler has a guarantee that the value `1` can fit in a `char` variable.

With a non constant `byte` variable, there is no such guarantee. [`byte` is signed, `char` is unsigned](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Answer (score 2):

You are running into [JLS-5.1.4 Widening and Narrowing Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.4),

> The following conversion combines both widening and narrowing primitive conversions:
>
> - `byte to char`
>
> First, the `byte` is converted to an `int` via widening primitive conversion ([§5.1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)), and then the resulting `int` is converted to a `char` by narrowing primitive conversion ([§5.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3)).

```
final byte b = 1;
char c = (char) ((int) 2); // <-- 2 is an int literal
c = (char) ((int) 1); // <-- b is 1 a byte literal
```

If you examine the bytescodes with `javap -v` you'll see the the value 1 has already replaced the variable `b` after compilation.

> ```
> public static void main(java.lang.String[]) throws java.lang.Exception;
>   descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
>   flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
>   Exceptions:
>     throws java.lang.Exception
>   Code:
>     stack=2, locals=3, args_size=1
>        0: iconst_1 
>        1: istore_1 // b = 1
>        2: iconst_2
>        3: istore_2 // c = 2
>        4: iconst_1 // integer1.
>        5: istore_2 // c = 1.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I guess that it happens because java compiler replaces references to `final` variables by their values (almost like pre-processor in C). Since value `1` is legal for type `char` the last line is transformed to

```
c = 1;
```

that is compiled successfully.

Comment: `final` variables with constant expressions. i.e. `byte a=1; final b=a; char c=b;` still fails.