# Confused on how java Java Arithmetic operation work in this case

Tags: java

I know that during java arithmetic operations data types like byte,short,and char values are automatically widened to int ,I understand why the following example **fails to compile** :

```
byte a = 10 ;
byte b = 20 ;          // compile fails
short sum = a + b ;
```

But what I didn't understand if we modify the preceding example and define variables **a** and **b** as final then its compiles successfully :

```
final byte a = 10 ;
final byte b = 20 ;  // compile successful
short sum = a + b ;
```

What I didn't understand here is how the key **final** assure the compiler to do the sum ?

Comment: This has been asked and answered several times before, FYI.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Maybe [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27044674/char-and-byte-with-final-access-modifier-java)?

Comment: @user1803551 - Yeah, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660856/promotion-in-java).